# How to source /etc/profile and .bashrc while starting vncserver

Tags: vnc, profile

I have an installation of RHEL5.10 (2.6.18-371.11.1.el5) with `vncserver`:

```
# rpm -qa | grep vnc
libvncserver-0.9.7-2.el5
vnc-server-4.1.2-14.el5_6.6
x11vnc-0.9.13-8.el5
```

While my other installations of same versions do `source /etc/profile` and `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`, this server ignores it.
Where should I look in order to find what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when started by a normal user, VNC reads `~/.vnc/xstartup` for its initialization. This is just a shell script, so you can put your environment settings, variables, and other configuration options there, as well as executing or sourcing other shell scripts as necessary.

Comment: So, neither `.profile` nor `.bashrc` is run without explicitly sourcing those in xstartup?